# searchBar textDidChange is called two times when search field taped in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar created programmatically in a function called from viewDidLoad in this way

```
//***************************************
//***  Build the UINavigationBar        *
//***************************************
- (void) buildBar {

    search = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    [search sizeToFit];
    search.delegate = self;
    [[search.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = search;

    tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 110.0f, 44.01f)];
   tools.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent; 
    if(tools.subviews.count >0)
    {
        [[[tools subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
    }
    NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
    [buttons addObject:[self editButtonItem]];
    bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(activateActions:)];

    bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;

    [buttons addObject:bi];
    [bi release];

    [tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];

    [buttons release];

    UIBarButtonItem *tollbarButtons = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = tollbarButtons; 

    [tollbarButtons release];

 //   [tools release];
//    [search release];
}
```

when i tap on the search field my [searchBar textDidChange] delegate is called two times and i cant figur it out, **It happend only on the first time when user tap the search field, is it normal response?.**
hear is the code

```
-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
      if([searchText length] == 0 && firstTimeSearch == NO ){
          firstTimeSearch = YES;
          [filterCalls removeAllObjects];
          [filterCalls addObjectsFromArray:allCalls];

/*          [searchBar performSelector: @selector(resignFirstResponder) 
                          withObject: nil 
                          afterDelay: 0.1];*/
    }
    else{
          firstTimeSearch = NO;
          [filterCalls removeAllObjects]; 
        [filteredCallsDetails removeAllObjects];

 //        
          int i = 0;
          for(NSDictionary *call in callsDetails ){

//              NSNumber *callId = [call objectForKey:@"CallID"];

              generalUtils *gu = [[generalUtils alloc]init];
              NSArray *callDetail = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[gu getFilteredCallDetails:i :filterCalls :filteredCallsDetails]]; 

              for (NSDictionary *answer in callDetail) {
                  NSRange r = [[answer objectForKey:@"answer"] rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
                  if(r.location != NSNotFound){

                      [filterCalls addObject:call]; 
                      [filteredCallsDetails addObject:callDetail];                  }

              }

              i++;
        }
    }
       [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I'm working in xCode 4.3.1
i know i have unexplained code in this function but even when i remark it it still called two times, trying to solve it but cant fined Y
be happy to get help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

instead of

```
 - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

Comment: OK so how i will get the Text from the searchfield?

Comment: @ShimonWiener searchBar.text will hold your search text

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i need to perform a search on my arrays of data as the user tap on the keyboard so i need to implement "textDidChange", do you know way it called two times?

Comment: To know that, just add a break point at  if([searchText length] == 0 && firstTimeSearch == NO ){ " line and you can watch the execution. Also try to minimize size of array if possible that may helpful to reduce time of debugging

Comment: i did that already, and i see the function is called two times, the arrays length is 25 its not taking to long about a second

Comment: **It happend only on the first time when user tap the search field, is it normal response?**

Comment: see this link, It may be problem like that http://jomnius.blogspot.in/2010/07/uitextfield-textfieldshouldbeginediting.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9104/discussion-between-shimon-wiener-and-rakeshns)

Comment: Sorry it was night when you invited me on chat. I fell sleep.